# centos blocking 22 port even if firewall close

Tags: centos, ssh, firewall

I'm trying ssh connection to server but it gives `port 22: Connection refused` error.

I checked firewall and it seems disabled

I also checked port 22 with `telnet` command and it seems blocked..

How can I allow port 22 for ssh connections while firewall already disabled ?

Comment: Is this a physical server or is it an instance in the cloud?

Comment: systemctl status sshd

Comment: @ItaiGanot physical server

Comment: @AnthonyFornito its active

Comment: netstat -an | grep 22 looking for LISTEN or ESTABLISHED

Comment: @AnthonyFornito thanks a lot, it uses different port instead of 22